# Update statement with self join in sybase

Tags: sql, sybase, self-join

I have one table which contain following data.

```
Emp_Id  Name    dept   cat
 1      abc             P
 1               HC     G
 2      def             P 
 2               ET     G
 3      ghi             P
 3               BC     G
 3               MN     G
 4      jkl             P
 4               LS     G
 4               LS     G
```

I want to update this table to have output records like.

```
Emp_Id     Name    dept    cat
     1      abc      HC     P
     2      def      ET     P
     3      ghi      BC     P
     4      jkl      LS     p
```

if Emp_Id is associated with two different dept then it should update any one of the dept (Emp_Id=3). if one Emp_Id is associated with two same dept then it should come once (Emp_Id=4). 
I am using below query

```
UPDATE Table1 
    SET a.dept = b.dept
    from Table1 a, Table1 b          
    WHERE
      a.Emp_Id=b.Emp_Id
      and a.cat='P'
```

but it is not updating anything for Emp_Id 3 and 4
Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Dhiraj

Comment: I got it myself....Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple steps  Psudeo code since I don't know sybase syntax well enough:

```
Get the results you're after in a select.
SELECT EMP_ID, max(name), max(Dept), max(cat)
FROM tableName
GROUP BY EMPI_ID
```

Insert those results into a temp table

Drop your table and recreate it from the temp table.